# How can i connect my acoustic guitar to speakers?

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I have Yamaha F310p guitar and now i want to connect it to speakers, it doesn't have any instrument or socket to connect it. Shall i need to attach some gadget. Its a simple acoustic guitar, so what should i do to connect it?

Comment: We could help more if you edit your question to include the reason you need to connect it to speakers. Is it for a specific performance, and if so, why can't you use it unamplified? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

Obviously you'll need an amplifier and speakers, many acoustic guitar amps 
are combos, i.e. the amplifier is integrated with the speakers.

The following or ordered from least invasive to most invasive:

**1. Use a microphone**
Get a microphone (or microphones), and a stand, point the microphone(s) at your guitar and play.  Depending on the microphones, and your amp, you may need to obtain a pre-amp in order to boost the microphone level signals up to the levels
expected by your amp.
This approach allows you to leave your guitar completely as it is. 
There is a degree of art in arranging and pointing the microphone(s) at
the guitar in order to get a good tone.  (I keep referring to microphones
since one approach involves using two microphones).  A potential drawback
of this approach is that the microphones may pick up (and amplify) other sounds
in the environment.

**2. Get a soundhole pickup**
There are devices that are magnetic pickups that you can place into the soundhole of your guitar.  Most of these are designed so that it is (relatively) easy to insert and remove these as you see fit; you'll again need cable(s) and an amplifier.  These are not sensitive to acoustic interference.

**3. Get a contact microphone**
There are contact microphones that you can install by placing the device in contact with the soundboard of the guitar.  Similar to the external microphones, i.e. depending on your amp, you may need a pre-amplifier.  Some of these are semi-permanent,
some are fully permanent.  Depending on how handy you are, you might be able to install one of these inside your guitar yourself.  Usually you don't have the option to easily remove the electronics from your guitar once you've installed them.  Similar to the normal microphone, there is some art in terms of where you
install the contact microphone in order to achieve a good tone.

**4. Take your guitar to a luthier**
A good luthier should be able to install an internal pickup or microphone, or
install a piezio pickup in the bridge of your guitar.  The upside is that they'll be able to more fully integrate the electronics with your guitar, e.g.
having the jack come out the bridge pin.  The downside is cost, and maybe time.

Also note that each of these options will end up sounding slightly different from one another.

Comment: I worked with a few contact mics on acoustic guitars over the weekend and they were definitely the worst of these possible options. Spending the extra money on a sound hole pickup is a much better option.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that simple ! Needed are - pick-up, or microphone; pre-amp;power amp; speakers. The pre- and power amps are often combined into 'an amp', and this is often combined with speaker/s, and called a combo.

The pick-up is a sort of 'mic.', which can be purchased to fit into or on your guitar. A lead will then go from this (you may have to make a plughole in the guitar) into the input of an amp. You could use a mic. in front of the guitar, but that incorporates keeping still.

Any amp will do the job, but an acoustic guitar amp is eq'd to give the best sound.

Last time I was faced with this problem, I sold the existing guitar and bought an electro-acoustic with the electronics  built in. The overall cost was similar to adapting the original acoustic - probably less if someone was to be paid to fit a pick-up.The strings will probably have to come off, so a change will be necessary - another expense.A big advantage of an electric-ready guitar is that it will have volume control and eq. already built in to the body, whereas an additional pick up on the original guitar will be just that, and afterwards you may well think the other option (change guitars) would have been a better one.

You've some serious thinking to do !!